# Post parameters encoding

Tags: php, apache

I'm new to apache and php. I use php5 and apache2. A form like:

```
<form action="index.php?act=adduser" method="post">
     Имя: <input type="text" name="name" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" required=""/>
     ...
</form>
```

After receiving the data (in russian) in index.php, I display it:

```
echo $_POST['name'];
```

But it displays rubbish, because somwhere, a wrong character encoding was used.
(It seems, like the POST data was encoded wrongly. I had similar problem with tomcat7, and solved it by adding a special SetCharacterEncodingFilter.) The ordinary text, written directly by `echo 'тест';` displays properly.
 How can I find the place, and where to set up it?

Comment: The answers from two mentioned questions don't work for my case.